# Formal verification of simple equational proofs (as in Universal Algebra...)?

Tags: lo.logic, mathematical-software

Is there an software package aimed at verfication of simple equational proofs?

I am hoping to avoid the usual overhead involved with First Order Logic or Higher Order Logic verification systems.

[Apologies for the 'software question', but formal verification usually involves this. :)  References to papers that might point me in the right direction would of course be appreciated.]

Comment: The best I can come up with are search phrases: term rewriting systems, unification, and Stanley Burris.  I don't know if Prof. Burris is still active, but he is the first person I would ask about your question.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.25 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMT (Satisfaction Modulo Theories) solving is pretty much the go-to technology for this these days, and works shockingly well in practice, often even on undecidable theories. Here are links to a few such projects (though there are many, many more implementations).

- CVC3: http://cs.nyu.edu/acsys/cvc3/
- OpenSMT: http://verify.inf.unisi.ch/opensmt
- Z3: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/
- STP: http://sites.google.com/site/stpfastprover/

The SMT-LIB webpage[1] is a central library organizing the efforts of many of these efforts as well as containing a specification of a common language for SMT solvers to take as input.

[1] http://combination.cs.uiowa.edu/smtlib/

Comment: Thanks for this.  Do you know if Stanley Burris is involved with any of these?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.26

Comment: Looking at his webpage, he certainly could be, but I don't actually know -- this kind of theorem proving is (a) a huge and extremely active area, and (b) just outside my own expertise. SMT is a very applied field, and as a result they are happy to use any mathematics from any area to make their programs run faster. 

Comment: I'll take a look at these, thanks.  Still, these support full first order logic, not just equational logic.  Is FOL the natural level of generality here?